# can I store an innerHTML of a div into a hidden text box in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I have to store the inner html of a table into a hidden input box. I am able to store it in a JavaScript variable but not been able to store it in the hidden input box.

Here is the code I have written so far:

in .JS file

```
d = document.getElementById('address').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('hid1').value = d;
```

in .php file

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid1" name="hid1"/>
```

Please help me with this...am really clueless on what to do

Comment: what you are looking for (if I understand you correctly) is possible, can you explain what you have done so far?

Comment: This *hid1* ID is unique?

Comment: @AnanthaSharma...see I want to store the innerHTML value of address div to a hidden input text box

Comment: Is the JS file loaded ? Can you check from browser...

Comment: And then you want to submit it as formdata?

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, the way you have it set up currently, you will need to append the `value` attribute to the `<input>` *before* assigning a value to that element's `value` property.

If you include the `value` attribute in your `HTML` from the start, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid1" name="hid1" value="" />
```

your `javascript` should work exactly as you intend.

Comment: I have figured out the reason...the issue is with the FORM...if I put the hidden field outside the FORM then its capturing the innerHTML value...

Answer (score 0):

[here is an implementation,](http://jsfiddle.net/ananthasharma/rjt4hvjy/) the textfield isn't hidden (for obvious reasons).. but hiding it shouldn't be a problem.

```
var data = document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = data;
```

this should do (ensure the id `hiddenField` is unique in the document or `hid1` in your case)

Comment: did the sample do what you expected? i built the solution based on that understanding.